# Integrating the trace of a matrix log and Stokes theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Consider the function $g(t) = \frac{\Im \text{Tr}}{2\pi}\log(X(t))$ with a  smooth one parameter family of unitary operators $X$. A quantity I'm looking for is described by $P = \int_\gamma dg$ where $\gamma$ is a curve parametrized on $[0,T]$. I have calculated $P$ by other means (for finite dimensional $X$) and it turns out that $P \neq \gamma(T)-\gamma(0) $ but that it's equal to $P = \frac{\Im \text{Tr}}{2\pi}\log(X(t)X^\dagger(0))$. The fact that Stokes theorem appears to break is probably a consequence of the log not behaving nicely, however, I have trouble identifying exactly what goes wrong and how arrive at the correct result.

Edit: Since the integral depends on the path here's the expression that should give $P = \frac{\Im \text{Tr}}{2\pi}\log(X(t)X^\dagger(0))$:
\begin{align}
P = \int^T_0 \partial_t g dt
\end{align}

Comment: You mean the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, quite simply. But, yes, the issue is whether there is a well-defined branch of the log along $\gamma$.

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is a special case of Stoke's theorem right? Is it preferred to name the more specific theorems in the mathematics community?

Comment: That makes sense. Are there any subtleties concerning the fact that I take the logarithm of an operator, or is it basically the same as for a complex scalar field? That still leaves the question on how to get the correct result.